# Manually created MacOS apps being deleted

Tags: macos, bundle, code-signing, .app, notarize

I have some standalone apps that I manually created on my macOS. They keep getting deleted from the Applications folder from time to time, not sure how or why.

The source app I use to create them, in Documents folder also gets deleted. I have a backup of it all so that's good, but it's annoying to have to copy them back.

I manually created the .app bundle and added the necessary folders and files inside. The apps I created basically run a .sh file to automate some tasks.

They're not code signed or notarized, so I am suspecting it's macOS protection that must be deleting them. And even though I tried to code sign and notarize, it seems I need a developer id, which I don't want to acquire.

Does anyone know why are they being deleted and how to prevent that?